# Retrieve rows where Column1 != Multiple Values from Column2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Location columns. I need to find a way to show only exceptions, where Location1 != Location2, **BUT** there are multiple values in Location2 column that can be associated with value in Lcoation1.

For example: San Diego in Location1 column can have 4 possible values in Location2 column (North, Central, South, San Diego) and such rows need to be excluded from the run. If San Diego in Location1 column and Seattle (for example) in Location2 column, that is considered as Exception.

```
create table Locations
(Id INT, Location1 VARCHAR(30), Location2 VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO Locations
VALUES
(1, 'San Diego', 'North'),
(2, 'San Diego', 'South'),
(3, 'San Diego', 'Central'),
(4, 'San Diego', 'Arizona'),
(5, 'San Diego', 'San Diego'),
(6, 'San Diego', 'Seattle'),
(7, 'San Diego', 'North'),
(8, 'San Diego', 'San Diego'),
(9, 'San Diego', 'Central'),
(10, 'San Diego', 'South')

SELECT * FROM Locations
```

I can exclude only obvious condition where Location 1 = Location 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM Locations
WHERE Location1 != Location2
```

Expected Output:

| Id | Lcoation1 | Location2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | San Diego | Arizona |
| 6 | San Diego | Seattle |

Comment: @squillman, that's the point. There is no association. Imagine that each Employee has 2 Location Addresses (Office Location and Working Area Location). Such data manually inserted by other employee. To exclude human error, when someone can accidentally assign San Diego as Office and Seattle as working area, I want to build something that will catch such things. If I need to manually hardcode it, no problem. Thank You

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment...  I still think you need something to systematically relate Location1 to Location2.  By hardcoding, I meant in the SQL Query itself, which I personally would be loathe to do.  I guess this is the reason that I never (ok, _very_ rarely) allow masterdata to be entered in a freetext input...  You can prevent such problems by limiting what the user is allowed to input.  At this point, though, it seems that would involve a bit of rearchitecture and (probably manual) data cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to do some manual (ongoing) maintenance, you could create a mapping table of valid `Location1`-`Location2` relations and filter `Locations` based on the mapping table.  This way *you* define what is valid and you can easily find things that aren't.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations;
CREATE TABLE Locations
(Id INT, Location1 VARCHAR(30), Location2 VARCHAR(30));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RegionMap;
CREATE TABLE RegionMap (Location1 VARCHAR(30), Location2 VARCHAR(30));

INSERT dbo.RegionMap (Location1, Location2)
VALUES ('San Diego', 'North'),
('San Diego', 'South'),
('San Diego', 'Central'),
('San Diego', 'San Diego');

INSERT INTO Locations
VALUES
(1, 'San Diego', 'North'),
(2, 'San Diego', 'South'),
(3, 'San Diego', 'Central'),
(4, 'San Diego', 'Arizona'),
(5, 'San Diego', 'San Diego'),
(6, 'San Diego', 'Seattle'),
(7, 'San Diego', 'North'),
(8, 'San Diego', 'San Diego'),
(9, 'San Diego', 'Central');

SELECT l.Location1, l.Location2
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN dbo.RegionMap m ON m.Location1 = l.Location1
                         AND m.Location2 = l.Location2
WHERE m.Location2 IS NULL;
```

Note here that I removed ID 10 (the 2nd instance of San Diego South) and you still get the proper results.

The drawback here is that you will have to put a process in place to maintain the mapping table.  If you run this query routinely and get a regular report of the output it'll help you to know what you might need to add to the mapping table.

But really, the best thing is to limit what the users can enter in as masterdata in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

`WITH TIES` in concert with the window function `sum() over()` could be an option here

**Example**

```
SELECT Top 1 with ties *
 FROM Locations
 Order By SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION2)
```

**Results**

```
Id  Location1   Location2
4   San Diego   Arizona
6   San Diego   Seattle
```

**Note:**  The `PARTITION BY` could include `LOCATION1` ... It is hard to tell with your sample data:

```
... SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION1,LOCATION2)
```

Comment: This is cool, and works for the result set (thanks for the lesson on WITH TIES!).  But I wonder if in the real world it's possible for, say, 'South' to only be present once...

Comment: @squillman Good question.  It is hard to know what the OP is really going after with such a small sample.

Comment: It worked for these sample data set, however when I exclude last row with South in the Location2 (to keep only 1 record of it), it treats it as exception.

I think I need hard coded it somehow...

Comment: @Yara1994 Hard to know what your goal is.  Is to to hard code the exclusions, or find exceptions for review.